# Visual Studio 2012 installations hangs at SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack installation after power failure

Tags: windows-7, installation, installer, visual-studio-2012

I was trying to install VS2012 Ultimate. During the installation, there was a power failure.  I restarted the PC, and started the installation again. The installation starts but it hangs on

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom
```

Next I tried to cancel the install, but the installation hangs with a message *"stopping installation"*.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm you have no ability to uninstall it first ? You may need to do a system restore

Comment: Can't uninstall, I'm looking for something to clean VS2012 registry keys can't seem to find any. Edit: I tried to run vs_ultimate.exe /Uninstall /Force then I get the message Access Denied  (same if try to uninstall from add/remove programs)

Comment: try uninstall instead of install using the same package.check whether there is `SQLDom.msi` in the installation file. try to install it manually.check what error you are getting

Comment: @DouglasDC3 right click on the program and click run as administrator.

Comment: No luck still getting ACcess Denied I'll need something to completely delete all registry entries so the installer thinks it has to start over